# How to display the date in letters - Javascript --> innerhtml?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleDateString();
document.getElementById("dt").innerHTML = n;
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="dt" style="color: white; position: absolute; right: 25px; top: 5px; font-size: 25px;"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: <p id="dt" style="color: white; position: absolute; right: 25px; top: 5px; font-size: 25px;"></p>
  <script>
   var d = new Date();
   var n = d.toLocaleDateString();

   document.getElementById("dt").innerHTML = n;
  </script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const options = {
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric'
};

var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleDateString('en-EN', options);
document.getElementById("dt").innerHTML = n;
```

```html
<p id="dt"></p>
```